# JQuery mobile clicking inside Collapsible adds ui-mobile-viewport-transitioning viewport-slidefade to body, which hides the ability to scroll

Tags: jquery-mobile

Weirdest thing, using JQuery Mobile 1.2.0.  When a user travels to a page with a collapsible, clicking anywhere inside that collapsible div except on buttons adds ui-mobile-viewport-transitioning viewport-slidefade to the body, which is freezing the pane and hiding the scroll bar, and snapping the view to the top of the page.  Before click :

```
<body class="ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-c">
```

After clicking inside a collapsible (Not anywhere else):

```
<body class="ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-c ui-mobile-viewport-transitioning viewport-slidefade">
```

If I f5 and reload the page, it doesn't do this anymore.  Only after following a link.

Example of a link that leads to the page :

```
<a href="ax_mer_view.cfm?MERID=XXX" class="ui-link-inherit">
<h3>Info here
</a>
```

This is happening on every single page across our entire mobile application, no matter the browser.  iOS, Android, Chrome on PC, Firefox on PC, etc.

Comment: Upgrade to version 1.4.5, old versions are no longer supported.